# Display HTML while PHP is processing

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have a PHP script that takes around 1 minute 20 seconds to load as it fetches data from other websites. However I need some way to show the user that the page is loading. Something like 'This page is loading and may take up to 2 minutes' with a .gif loading images.

I have tried jquery:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <script>
      // Put an animated GIF image insight of content
      $("#content").empty().html('<img src="http://www.website.com/images/loading.gif" />');

      // Make AJAX call
      $("#content").load("http://website.com/page.php")
      </script>

<div id="content">
Content to load here!
</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

But the page is blank (don't know if i'm implementing something wrong).

Is there any other way of doing so?

I have looked at other questions but can't find anything that matches what I need, that I can get to work.

Thanks,

Jack.

Comment: Hum, where is the #content div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you got the `script` tags wrong. you need to close the `script` with the `src` call, and open a new one for the actual code

Also, you need to load the DOM **before** using JQuery to fetch objects. You can use `$(document).ready()` or place your script after the DOM element.

Comment: where is the `#content` element itself? JQuery can't fetch a non-existing element

Comment: I have it below the script just didn't include in code, will update again.

Comment: here is your answer. It should be above the script. That is the DOM element should be prepared prior to fetching it

Answer (score 4):

You won't get a response from the server, until the script has finished loading. Therefor you have to 'prepend' the page with another page, which shows the loading part. That page should call the script you want to execute, through for example an AJAX call.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an AJAX call with `beforeSend` and `success` events:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://website.com/page.php", type: "POST",
   beforeSend: function() {
      $("#content").html('<img src="images/loading.gif" />');
   },
   success: function(data) {
      $("#content").html(data);
   }
})
```

Comment: Are you running the JS code on DOM ready? In your code example you are not.. (see Eoin Murphy's answer)

Answer (score 0):

Where is your jquery loaded in the file? If its loaded at the top, you should wait for the dom to load before executing its JS.

http://api.jquery.com/ready/